# Find the $2022$th derivative $f^{(2022)}(0)$ of the function $f(x) = x^{2019}\cos(x)$.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Find $f^{(2022)}(0)$  of the function

$$f(x)=x^{2019} \cos x.$$

By Taylor series at the point $x =0$, my answer was $0$.

But someone who gave this question to me said the answer is like the below picture.

Who is correct?

Did I something wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct; the coefficient of $x^{2022}$ in the Taylor series of $x^{2019}\cos x$ at $x=0$ is $0$, which implies that the 2022th derivative at $0$ is $0$.

Your friend made the following error. Yes, all the terms but the $k=2019$th one dissapear. But this means s/he should have $\cos^{(2022-2019)}(0) = \cos'''(0) = -\sin(0) = 0.$

Answer (score 10):

Since $f$ is an odd function, every $f^{(n)}$ with even $n$ is odd too, and therefore $n\text{ even}\implies f^{(n)}(0)=0$.